# Adding labels for graphael bar charts?

Tags: raphael, graphael

I am using graphael to draw barcharts for my data, and couldn't figure out how to give the bar charts a label.

```
var r = Raphael(element);
r.hbarchart(10, 20, 500, 220, barData, {colors:colors, type:'square'}).hover(fin, fout);
```

Comment: where are you expecting the labels to be?

Comment: I was hoping for labels to the side of the bars to explain what the bars represent. It's pretty useless to have a bar chart with no labels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `label` on your chart object.

```
  var barChart = r.g.barchart(0, 0, 200, 200, [3,2,1]);
  barChart.label(['a','b','c']);
```

Comment: label() is broken on the current version of gRaphael's barchart.